# Firebase push not showing in banner while in background

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I use firebase to send push notifications to my app. I use alert view to display the message received from firebase and it works fine, but while in background the notification banner does not appear in notifications but the `didreceiveremotenotifications` method is called properly.  can't find out what is the problem. please advice

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject])
{
    if isBackground == false
    {
        let notifiAlert = UIAlertView()
        let NotificationMessage : AnyObject? =  userInfo["alert"]
        notifiAlert.title = userInfo["title"] as! String
        notifiAlert.message = NotificationMessage as? String
        notifiAlert.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
        notifiAlert.show()
    }
    else
    {
        print(userInfo)
          NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("pushReceived", object: userInfo)
    }
}
```

in the above while in background, the user info is printed as follow

```
[title: Check your billing details, notification: 
{
   body = test;
   e = 1;
   title = "test notification";
}, collapse_key: com.softence.viabill, 
url: http://softence.com/devTest/viabill-sample-app/main.html?, 
    message: Please check the latest generated bill, from: 314848715780]
```

Comment: make sure your `addObserver` initialised before you call `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("pushReceived", object: userInfo)`

Comment: @Dharmesh Kheni yeah it is initialised in the view controller's view will appear and post notification is called only when push is received